# Write Basic HTML in sonata edit Tab

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin, sonata

So in my sonata admin CMS, I'm trying to add a page called info

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
            ->tab('Info')
            ->end();
}
```

In my admin.yml I have this under calls:

```
calls:
- [ setTemplates, [{edit: admin\virtual-event-info.html.twig }]]
```

And then in a twig file I have this

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}
<h1>I just want to write some basic static html out here</h1>
```

I just want to write out a basic static html page for FAQ's. I don't want to take any inputs or ask for any data, I just want a place for new people to know some basic info about that section of the CMS. Can anyone direct me on how to get that HTML to actually show under that tab?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should put your html content inside the `{% block form %}`. That will replace the original content defined in the extended template (vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig).

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}
{% block form %}
  <h1>This replaces the base edit form block content</h1>
{% endblock %}
```